# group by and count within a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm trying to filter out my (users table) data with conditions derived from data in (users_status table).

The **users** table is a table containing user ids and usernames

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(25),
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The **groups** table is a table containing group ids

```
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(25),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The **user_status** table is a table containing a log of activity. The way it works is while a user is in a **group** that user can toggle "bookmarked" between "on" or "off".

```
CREATE TABLE `user_status` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` int(10) unsigned,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned,
  `bookmarked` enum('on', 'off'),
  `date` datetime,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `group_id` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `groups` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now what I'm trying to do is retrieve all the users that either have no entries in **user_status** or the last entry in user_status is **"off"**

I have an SQL fiddle with an incomplete subquery where I tried doing this but I'm not getting this working.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d5b4/2

```
select us.id, us.group_id, g.name as GROUP_NAME, us.user_id, u.username as USER_USERNAME, us.bookmarked, us.date 
from user_status us
inner join users u ON u.id = us.user_id
inner join groups g ON g.id = us.group_id
where 'on' != (
    select bookmarked
    from user_status
    group by (group_id, user_id)
    where group_id = us.group_id AND user_id = us.user_id
    order by ID DESC
    limit 1;
);
```

**EDIT 6:28 pm**
So given **user_status**

```
select * from user_status order by group_id, user_id, date;
+----+----------+---------+------------+--------------------------------+
| ID | GROUP_ID | USER_ID | BOOKMARKED |              DATE              |
+----+----------+---------+------------+--------------------------------+
|  1 |        1 |       1 | on         | January, 16 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|  2 |        1 |       1 | off        | January, 17 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|  3 |        1 |       1 | on         | January, 18 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|  9 |        1 |       1 | on         | January, 18 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|  7 |        1 |       2 | on         | January, 16 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|  8 |        1 |       2 | off        | January, 17 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|  4 |        2 |       1 | on         | January, 16 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|  5 |        2 |       1 | off        | January, 17 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|  6 |        2 |       1 | on         | January, 18 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
+----+----------+---------+------------+--------------------------------+
```

I would expect

group_id (1) user_id (1) 
**not returned** because the last bookmarked was 'on'

group_id (1) user_id (2) 
**returned** because the last bookmarked was 'off'

group_id (2) user_id (1) 
**not returned** because the last bookmarked was 'on'

user_id (3) 
**returned** because not present in user_status
note: user_id 3 was not added in the original sql fiddle example

Comment: Please clarify. Given your test result set, which users should be returned? User two has a last entry of `off`, and user three has _no entries_ in `user_status`. Should one or both be returned?

Comment: Please clarify once more: so user_id=3 should be returned for group_id=1 AND group_id=2, user_id=2 should be returned for group_id=2, as no row in user_status

Comment: Hi Eugen, user_id=3 should just be returned once because it is not present at all in user_status.

Comment: That appears to be exactly what my answer already does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes that a user can have different bookmark status for different groups at the same time.

It finds the most recent date for each (user_id, group_id) combination, then finds the record that corresponds to that.

Either the bookmark needs to be `'off'` or `NULL` as dictated by the `WHERE` clause.

It is possible for a user with no records in `user_group` to be returned due to the use of `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT
  u.*,
  g.*,
  us.*
FROM
  users         AS u
LEFT JOIN
  (
  SELECT user_id, group_id, MAX(date) AS date
    FROM user_status
GROUP BY user_id, group_id
  )
                AS us_newest
    ON  us_newest.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN
  user_status   AS us
    ON  us.user_id  = us_newest.user_id
    AND us.group_id = us_newest.group_id
    AND us.date     = us_newest.date
LEFT JOIN
  groups        AS g
   ON  g.id = us.group_id
WHERE
     us.bookmarked = 'off'
  OR us.bookmarked IS NULL
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d5b4/26

Comment: I liked this one best, it gives more room for organised tweaks, thank you

Answer (score 1):

1- you using `group by` before `WHERE` clause

2- you are grouping by two columns in subquery while you should group by one columns

try this  working query

```
select us.id, us.group_id, g.name as GROUP_NAME, us.user_id, u.username as USER_USERNAME, us.bookmarked, us.date 
from user_status us
inner join users u ON u.id = us.user_id
inner join groups g ON g.id = us.group_id
where 'on' != (
              select bookmarked
              from user_status

              where group_id = us.group_id AND user_id = us.user_id
              group by (group_id)  --->// you can choose to group by user_id or this.
              order by ID DESC
              limit 1
              );
```

[**fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d5b4/11)

Comment: same no results returned

Answer (score 1):

I'd try a filtered join, as this performs much better than a subquery with big data sets:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  groups.id AS groupid,
  users.id AS userid,
  groups.name AS groupname
FROM user_status
INNER JOIN users ON user_status.user_id=users.id
INNER JOIN groups ON user_status.group_id=groups.id
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT
    user_id,
    group_id,
    MAX(`date`) AS maxondate
   FROM user_status
   WHERE bookmarked='on'
   GROUP BY user_id, group_id
  ) AS ondate ON ondate.group_id=groups.id AND ondate.user_id=users.id
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT
    user_id,
    group_id,
    MAX(`date`) AS maxoffdate
   FROM user_status
   WHERE bookmarked='off'
   GROUP BY user_id, group_id
  ) AS offdate ON offdate.group_id=groups.id AND offdate.user_id=users.id
WHERE
  maxondate IS NULL
  OR (
    maxondate IS NOT NULL
    AND maxoffdate IS NOT NULL
    AND maxondate<maxoffdate
  )
```

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d5b4/21)

Comment: This doesn't return user three though, who has no records in `user_status`.

Comment: User three is in no groups as given in the OP's test data

Comment: Correct. _either have no entries in user_status or the last entry in user_status is "off"_ so user three should be returned, no?

Comment: If you read it this way, you would need to include a row for every user and every group he is **not** in - so I read it as "users in groups, but not currently bookmarked"

Comment: hi Eugen, that's a good observation however it's ok for it to just be returned once if he just has no record in user_status.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d5b4/32) :

```
SELECT us.id, us.group_id, g.name AS GROUP_NAME, u.id AS user_id, u.username AS USER_USERNAME, us.bookmarked, us.date
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_status us ON u.id = us.user_id AND us.bookmarked = 'off'
LEFT OUTER JOIN groups g ON g.id = us.group_id
WHERE  us.date = (SELECT max(ss.date) FROM user_status ss WHERE ss.user_id = us.user_id)
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_status ss WHERE ss.user_id = u.id)
```

Comment: this looks pretty simple and straightforward thank you let me test it a bit more